# Pandas Merge Not Working When Values Are an Exact Match

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my code and Dataframes. `stats_df` is much bigger. Not sure if it matters, but the column values are EXACTLY as they appear in the actual files. I can't merge the two DFs without losing 'Alex Len' even though both DFs have the same PlayerID value of '20000852'

```
stats_df = pd.read_csv('stats_todate.csv')
matchup_df = pd.read_csv('matchup.csv')

new_df = pd.merge(stats_df, matchup_df[['PlayerID','Matchup','Started','GameStatus']])
```

I have also tried:

```
stats_df['PlayerID'] = stats_df['PlayerID'].astype(str)
matchup_df['PlayerID'] = matchup_df['PlayerID'].astype(str)
stats_df['PlayerID'] = stats_df['PlayerID'].str.strip()
matchup_df['PlayerID'] = matchup_df['PlayerID'].str.strip()
```

Any ideas?

Here are my two Dataframes:

DF1:

```
PlayerID    SeasonType  Season  Name    Team    Position
20001713    1   2018    A.J. Hammons    MIA C
20002725    2   2022    A.J. Lawson ATL SG
20002038    2   2021    Ã‰lie Okobo BKN PG
20002742    2   2022    Aamir Simms NY  PF
20000518    3   2018    Aaron Brooks    MIN PG
20000681    1   2022    Aaron Gordon    DEN PF
20001395    1   2018    Aaron Harrison  DAL SG
20002680    1   2022    Aaron Henry PHI SF
20002005    1   2022    Aaron Holiday   PHO PG
20001981    3   2018    Aaron Jackson   HOU PF
20002539    1   2022    Aaron Nesmith   BOS SF
20002714    1   2022    Aaron Wiggins   OKC SG
20001721    1   2022    Abdel Nader PHO SF
20002251    2   2020    Abdul Gaddy OKC PG
20002458    1   2021    Adam Mokoka CHI SG
20002619    1   2022    Ade Murkey  SAC PF
20002311    1   2022    Admiral Schofield   ORL PF
20000783    1   2018    Adreian Payne   ORL PF
20002510    1   2022    Ahmad Caver IND PG
20002498    2   2020    Ahmed Hill  CHA PG
20000603    1   2022    Al Horford  BOS PF
20000750    3   2018    Al Jefferson    IND C
20001645    1   2019    Alan Williams   BKN PF
20000837    1   2022    Alec Burks  NY  SG
20001882    1   2018    Alec Peters PHO PF
20002850    1   2022    Aleem Ford  ORL SF
20002542    1   2022    Aleksej PokuÅ¡evski OKC PF
20002301    3   2021    Alen Smailagic  GS  PF
20001763    1   2019    Alex Abrines    OKC SG
20001801    1   2022    Alex Caruso CHI SG
20000852    1   2022    Alex Len    SAC C
```

DF2:

```
PlayerID    Name    Date    Started Opponent    GameStatus  Matchup
20000681    Aaron Gordon    4/1/2022    1   MIN     16
20002005    Aaron Holiday   4/1/2022    0   MEM     21
20002539    Aaron Nesmith   4/1/2022    0   IND     13
20002714    Aaron Wiggins   4/1/2022    1   DET     14
20002311    Admiral Schofield   4/1/2022    0   TOR     10
20000603    Al Horford  4/1/2022    1   IND     13
20002542    Aleksej PokuÅ¡evski 4/1/2022    1   DET     14
20000852    Alex Len    4/1/2022    1   HOU     22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the column you want to merge on using the `on` keyword argument:

```
new_df = pd.merge(stats_df, matchup_df[['PlayerID','Matchup','Started','GameStatus']], on=['PayerID'])
```

Otherwise it will merge using all of the shared columns.

Here is the explanation from the pandas docs:

> `on` : label or list
> Column or index level names to join on. These must be found in both
> DataFrames. If `on` is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults
> to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

Comment: thank you. i thought the first column name implied that. this works